# Android getDatabase called recursively error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hi I am trying to populate a database with a series of questions, but I can't get tables to be populated by the questions to retrieve into the app. I'm getting this error(full error log attached):

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hp.demo/com.example.hp.demo.MainActivityQuizBasics}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJNIH.png)

I have been trying for the past hour to try and resolve this but I can't work out how to fix this. I know it's to do with calling the getWritableDatabase functions in the addQuestions methods but I don't know what to do to fix it. If anyone has any suggestions that would be much appreciated.

**MainActivityQuizBasics**

```
package com.example.hp.demo;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.hp.demo.DbHelper.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.hp.demo.Model.QuestionBasics;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivityQuizBasics extends AppCompatActivity {
public int score = 0;
public ArrayList<String> wrongQuestListBasics = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> selectedBasics = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> actualAnswerBasics = new ArrayList<String>();
List<QuestionBasics> quesList1;
int ctr1 = 1;
QuestionBasics currentQ1;
TextView txtQuestion1;
RadioGroup grp;
RadioButton rda1, rdb1, rdc1, rdd1;
Button butNext1;
Random random1 = new Random();
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
TextView textViewTime1;
int number;
ProgressBar progressBar;
int progress = 1;
String tableName = "", catName = "";
TextView qstnNo;
DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions_basics);

    mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this,"blah blah blah", null,1);
    QuestionBasics myQuestion = new QuestionBasics(
            "What is note X?",
            "It's not a note",
            "A note that only xylophones can make.",
            "A note when a bowed instrument is played with two bows",
            "A synthesised x wave","It's not a note",
            "Basics");


    //mDBHlpr.addQuestionsBasics(myQuestion);

    List<QuestionBasics> mylist =  mDBHlpr.getAllQuestions1(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_QUEST1,"doesnotmatter");
    for (QuestionBasics q: mylist) {
        Log.d("QUESTIONS",q.getQUESTION1());
    }

    qstnNo = findViewById(R.id.qstnNo);

    Intent iin = getIntent();
    Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

    if (b != null) {
        tableName = (String) b.get("table_name");
        catName = (String) b.get("level_name");
        Log.d("Table Name", tableName);
        Log.d("Level Name", catName);
    }
    number = 0;
    //DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    //db.addBasicsTable(tableName,catName);
    //timer
    textViewTime1 = findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(1800000, 1000);
    timer.start();
//        quesList1 = db.getAllQuestions1("questBasics", catName);
//        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
//            while (true) {
//                int next = random1.nextInt(50);
//                if (!list.contains(next)) {
//                    list.add(next);
//                    break;
//                }
//            }
//        }
    //layout content
    currentQ1 = quesList1.get(0);
    txtQuestion1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rda1 = findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb1 = findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc1 = findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    rdd1 = findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    butNext1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    setQuestionView();
    grp = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    butNext1.setEnabled(false);

    grp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            if (i == R.id.radio0 || i == R.id.radio1 || i == R.id.radio2 || i == R.id.radio3)
                butNext1.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setMax(30);
    progressBar.setProgress(1);
    //checking answer
    butNext1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progress = progress + 1;
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            RadioButton answer = findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            //Log.d("yourans", currentQ1.getANSWER1() + " " + answer.getText());
            if (currentQ1.getANSWER1().equals(answer.getText())) {
                score++;
                //Log.d("score", "Your score" + score1);
            } else {
                wrongQuestListBasics.add(number, currentQ1.getQUESTION1());
                selectedBasics.add(number, answer.getText().toString());
                actualAnswerBasics.add(number, currentQ1.getANSWER1());
                number++;
            }
            grp.clearCheck();
            butNext1.setEnabled(false);
            //finishing quiz
            if (ctr1 < 31) {
                if (ctr1 == 30) {
                    butNext1.setText("End Quiz");
                }
                currentQ1 = quesList1.get(list.get(ctr1));
                setQuestionView();
            } else {
                timer.onFinish();
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    });

}

public void showResult() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityQuizBasics.this, ResultActivity.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("scoreBasics", score);//Your score
    b.putString("section", "questBasics");//Your table name
    b.putString("category", catName);//Your category name
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("wrongQuestions", wrongQuestListBasics);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("selectedAnswer", selectedBasics);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("actualAnswer", actualAnswerBasics);
    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

private void setQuestionView() {
    txtQuestion1.setText(currentQ1.getQUESTION1());
    rda1.setText(currentQ1.getOPTA1());
    rdb1.setText(currentQ1.getOPTB1());
    rdc1.setText(currentQ1.getOPTC1());
    rdd1.setText(currentQ1.getOPTD1());
    if (ctr1 < 10)
        qstnNo.setText("0" + ctr1 + "/30");
    else
        qstnNo.setText("" + ctr1 + "/30");
    ctr1++;
}  

}   

}
}
```

**EDITED - implemented suggested changes**
**DBhelper**

```
package com.example.hp.demo.DbHelper;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.example.hp.demo.Model.QuestionBasics;
import com.example.hp.demo.Model.QuestionChords;
import com.example.hp.demo.Model.QuestionScales;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Quiz.db";
public static final String TABLE_SCORE = "score";
public static final String SCORE_KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String SCORE_KEY_SECTION = "section";
public static final String SCORE_KEY_CAT = "category";
public static final String SCORE_KEY_SCORE = "score";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
private static final String KEY_OPTA = "opta"; //option a
private static final String KEY_OPTB = "optb"; //option b
private static final String KEY_OPTC = "optc"; //option c
private static final String KEY_OPTD = "optd"; //option d
private static final String KEY_CAT = "category"; //category
private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "questScales";
public static final String TABLE_QUEST1 = "questBasics";
private static final String TABLE_QUEST2 = "questChords";
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name,         SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    this.db = db;

    String basicsTableCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST1 + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTD + " TEXT, " + KEY_CAT + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(basicsTableCreate);
    addQuestionsBasics(db)


    String scoresTableCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_SCORE + " ( "
            + SCORE_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + SCORE_KEY_SECTION
            + " TEXT, " + SCORE_KEY_CAT + " TEXT, " + SCORE_KEY_SCORE + " INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(scoresTableCreate);
}


private void addQuestionsBasics(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    QuestionBasics q101 = new QuestionBasics("What is pitch?", "The length of a sound", "The overall quality of a sound", "The highness or lowness of a sound", "The volume of a sound", "The highness or lowness of a sound", "B");
    this.addQuestionBasics(q101,db);
    QuestionBasics q102 = new QuestionBasics("What is 'timbre'?", "The ove", "format it", "compile it", "hardware it", "format it", "B");
    this.addQuestionBasics(q102,db);
    QuestionBasics q103 = new QuestionBasics("What is rhythm?", "The sound a metronome makes", "The organisation of music through time", "A beat that repeats itself", "The amount of beats in a bar", "The organisation of music through time", "B");
    this.addQuestionBasics(q103,db);
    QuestionBasics q104 = new QuestionBasics("What is harmony?", "A series of pitches creating a musical statement", "The result of multiple notes played simultaneously", "A strong match between 2 different notes", "The sound a chord makes when the notes are in the correct key", "A strong match between 2 different notes", "B");
    this.addQuestionBasics(q104,db);
    QuestionBasics q105 = new QuestionBasics("What is a 'melody'?", "A strong rhythm that keeps the tune going", "A series of pitches that form a musical statement", "A set of chords that works well together", "A short motif to transition 2 sections of a song", "A series of pitches that form a musical statement", "B");
    this.addQuestionBasics(q105,db);
    QuestionBasics q106 = new QuestionBasics("What is 'dynamics'?", "Changes in textures, such as switching instruments", "Variations in loudness and softness", "The movement of music between different keys", "The way the melody of a song integrates with the chords", "Variations in loudness and softness", "B");
    this.addQuestionBasics(q106,db);
    QuestionBasics q107 = new QuestionBasics("What two note note pairs have no sharp or flat between them?", "DE, AB", "DF, BC", "BC ,DE", "EF, BC", "EF, BC", "B");
    this.addQuestionBasics(q107,db);
    QuestionBasics q108 = new QuestionBasics("What is pitch?", "The length of a sound", "The overall quality of a sound", "The highness or lowness of a sound", "The volume of a sound", "The highness or lowness of a sound", "B");
    this.addQuestionBasics(q108,db);
    QuestionBasics q109 = new QuestionBasics("What is 'timbre'?", "The ove", "format it", "compile it", "hardware it", "format it", "B");
    this.addQuestionBasics(q109,db);
    QuestionBasics q110 = new QuestionBasics("What is rhythm?", "The sound a metronome makes", "The organisation of music through time", "A beat that repeats itself", "The amount of beats in a bar", "The organisation of music through time", "B");
    this.addQuestionBasics(q110,db);

//shortened for testing
}

public void addQuestionsBasics(QuestionBasics quest) {
    addQuestionBasics(quest,this.getWritableDatabase());
}

public void addQuestionBasics(QuestionBasics quest,SQLiteDatabase db) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION1());
    contentValues.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER1());
    contentValues.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA1());
    contentValues.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB1());
    contentValues.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC1());
    contentValues.put(KEY_OPTD, quest.getOPTD1());
    contentValues.put(KEY_CAT, quest.getCATEGORY1());
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_QUEST1, null, contentValues);
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST1);
    onCreate(db);
}

public List<QuestionBasics> getAllQuestions1(String tname, String lname) {
    List<QuestionBasics> quesList1 = new ArrayList<QuestionBasics>();
    String selectQuery1 = "SELECT  * FROM " + tname + " WHERE " + KEY_CAT + " = '" + lname + "'";
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery1, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            QuestionBasics quest1 = new QuestionBasics();
            quest1.setID1(cursor.getInt(0));
            quest1.setQUESTION1(cursor.getString(1));
            quest1.setANSWER1(cursor.getString(2));
            quest1.setOPTA1(cursor.getString(3));
            quest1.setOPTB1(cursor.getString(4));
            quest1.setOPTC1(cursor.getString(5));
            quest1.setOPTD1(cursor.getString(6));
            quesList1.add(quest1);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return quest list
    return quesList1;
}

public List<QuestionScales> getAllQuestions(String tname, String lname) {
    List<QuestionScales> quesList1 = new ArrayList<QuestionScales>();
    String selectQuery1 = "SELECT  * FROM " + tname + " WHERE " + KEY_CAT + " = '" + lname + "'";
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery1, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            QuestionScales quest1 = new QuestionScales();
            quest1.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            quest1.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
            quest1.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
            quest1.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
            quest1.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
            quest1.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
            quest1.setOPTD(cursor.getString(6));
            quesList1.add(quest1);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return quest list
    return quesList1;
}

public boolean insertScoreBasics(int scoreBasics, String tname, String cname) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(SCORE_KEY_SECTION, tname);
    contentValues.put(SCORE_KEY_CAT, cname);
    contentValues.put(SCORE_KEY_SCORE, scoreBasics);
    long resultscore = db.insert(TABLE_SCORE, null, contentValues);
    if (resultscore == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public int getScoreBasics() {
    Cursor c;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT MAX(" + SCORE_KEY_SCORE + ") FROM " + TABLE_SCORE + " WHERE " + SCORE_KEY_SECTION + " = '" + TABLE_QUEST1 + "' AND " + SCORE_KEY_CAT + " = " + "'I'";
    c = db.rawQuery(sqlSelectQuery, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    int x = c.getInt(0);
    return x;
}
}
```

**xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context=".MainActivityQuizBasics">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_background_pink">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/qstnNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="01/30"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="05:00"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:max="30" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.03">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="RadioButton"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />


    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:background="@color/deeppurple"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="NEXT"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue(s ***(as the issue is repeated)***) are that you are using methods that will call the getWriteableDatabase and try to open the database via getWritableDatabase before the database has been properly opened.

e.g. in onCreate you call **addQuestionsBasics();** that's where you get the recursion. Instead of using **this** to refer to the database, you need to pass the SQliteDatabase as passed to the **onCreate** method to the **addQuestionsBasics();** and use that.

As such change **addQuestionsBasics(the_question);** to

:-

```
private void addQuestionsBasics(thequestion, SQliteDatabase db) {

    QuestionBasics q101 = new QuestionBasics("What is pitch?", "The length of a sound", "The overall quality of a sound", "The highness or lowness of a sound", "The volume of a sound", "The highness or lowness of a sound", "B");
    db.addQuestionBasics(q101); //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
    QuestionBasics q102 = new QuestionBasics("What is 'timbre'?", "The ove", "format it", "compile it", "hardware it", "format it", "B");
    db.addQuestionBasics(q102); //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
    ....... and so on
```

And in the onCreate method change to use :-

```
db.execSQL(basicsTableCreate);
addQuestionsBasics(db);
```

You also need the public **addQuestionsBasics** methods to be able to handle a call with and without the database being provided.

To do this have 2 **public void addQuestionsBasics** methods with signatures (the shorter with just a question as it's argument can call the longer version)

e.g. :-

```
    String basicsTableCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST1 + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTD + " TEXT, " + KEY_CAT + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(basicsTableCreate);
    addQuestionsBasics(db);

     //............. code shortened for test ..........
}

private void addQuestionsBasics(SQLiteDatabase db) { //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
    QuestionBasics q101 = new QuestionBasics("What is pitch?", "The length of a sound", "The overall quality of a sound", "The highness or lowness of a sound", "The volume of a sound", "The highness or lowness of a sound", "B");
    this.addQuestionBasics(q101,db);
    QuestionBasics q102 = new QuestionBasics("What is 'timbre'?", "The ove", "format it", "compile it", "hardware it", "format it", "B");
    this.addQuestionBasics(q102,db);

    //............. code shortened for test ..........
}

//<<<<<<<<<< NEW >>>>>>>>>>
public void addQuestionsBasics(QuestionBasics quest) {
    addQuestionBasics(quest,this.getWritableDatabase());
}

public void addQuestionBasics(QuestionBasics quest, SQLiteDatabase db) { //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION1());
    contentValues.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER1());
    contentValues.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA1());
    contentValues.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB1());
    contentValues.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC1());
    contentValues.put(KEY_OPTD, quest.getOPTD1());
    contentValues.put(KEY_CAT, quest.getCATEGORY1());
    // Inserting Row
    dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST1, null, contentValues);
```

### IMPORTANT

The above is needs to be repeated throughout for the other tables and for all rows being added and for all the respective methods.

Based on the above (note ONLY 2 questions) using the following in an activity *(with the **getAllQuestions1** method tweaked to select all rows)* :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this,"blah blah blah", null,1);
        QuestionBasics myQuestion = new QuestionBasics(
                "What is note X?",
                "It's not a note",
                "A note that only xylophones can make.",
                "A note when a bowed instrument is played with two bows",
                "A synthesised x wave","Something Esle",
                "Wierdness");


        mDBHlpr.addQuestionsBasics(myQuestion); //<<<<<<<<<< ADD another question

        List<QuestionBasics> mylist =  mDBHlpr.getAllQuestions1(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_QUEST1,"doesnotmatter");
        for (QuestionBasics q: mylist) {
            Log.d("QUESTIONS",q.getQUESTION1());
        }
    }
}
```

The result is :-

> ```
> 05-23 11:05:48.911 22414-22414/? D/QUESTIONS: What is pitch?
> 05-23 11:05:48.911 22414-22414/? D/QUESTIONS: What is 'timbre'?
> 05-23 11:05:48.911 22414-22414/? D/QUESTIONS: What is note X?
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I have done this but am now getting a 'cannot resolve method' error on each of the db.addQuestionBasics(q101); lines. Do you know how I could fix this? Thank you sir :)

Comment: @edpor oops missed part of it bear with me will create a working version and test.

Comment: Hi Mike thanks very much for your reply. I have implemented the changes, as show above but am now getting a null pointer error on line 98 in main quiz activity( wich is this line: currentQ1 = quesList1.get(0);)  wich is caused by Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: I am very appreciative of any help sir, if i can get this working I will be over the moon! THanks for your help so far i appreciate your time

Comment: @edpor you should ask a new question and include the stack-trace.  If you don'st know what a stack-trace is then have a look at [Debug your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) You shouldn't really ask a question and then edit it so drastically. This is because the answer will then not relate to the problem and others would not be able to get assistance.

Comment: @edpor I've had a quick look BUT there's simply too much missing code (layouts other activities). You need to whittle the code down to a much smaller size (as an example look at how I whittled down the code for the answer).

Comment: Hi Mike thanks for your reply, I have removed excess code and added the xml file, if it helps. I will be asking a new question however, and I appreciate the advice you have given me :) , I apologise for being lazy with my formatting and question.